# Сборка проектов с GoClipse

Tags: golang, eclipse

Возможно ли положить в папку cmd несколько файлов `.go`. Идея в том, что если я так сделаю, то собрать в eclipse у меня не получается, выдается много ошибок, а если делать это с помощью go build то все собирается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть в баг-трекер проекта, то там очень много на эту тему. Вообще, так делать нельзя. Но можно сделать хак, в папке `cmd` создать папку `main` (или любую другую), и туда  положить все файлы.

P. S. После того, как вы переместите файлы, не забудьте поменять в настройках путь к главному файлу `.go`.